# How to force Motorola 2180 mobile computer to be recognized as mobile device in ASP.NET MVC4 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile, windows-ce

In ASP.NET MVC4 application

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice
```

is used to detect mobile devices. It returns false for MC2180.

Application contains views with .Mobile as part on view name for mobile devices. Those views are not rendered, regular browser views appear.

Application is browser application which renders different views in browser on mobile and non-mobile devices.

51 degrees mobi module from  http://51degrees.codeplex.com/ free version is also installed.

If Motorola MC2180 mobile computer/handheld scanner  is used to log on to application, is is not detected as mobile device: .Mobile views are not executed, usual views appears.

How to force it to be recognized as mobile device ? Device is running Windows CE 6.0 and it contains Motorola Rhoelements RHOS custom browser which returns version string as

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows CE 6.0) AppleWebKit/534.51 (KHTML, like Gecko) MotorolaWebKit/2.1.8.7 Safari/534.51
```

Application should in Mono and in ASP.NET 4. jQuery and jQuery-mobile are used in mobile views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the User Agent you've given, I've managed to get the device recognised as a mobile device using [www.detectmobilebrowsers.com](http://www.detectmobilebrowsers.com). It uses a Regex to evaluate the user agent and has many examples posted in various languages.

I've adapted the example into a method that you can call;

```
public bool DeviceIsMobile(string userAgent)
{
  Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
  Regex regex2 = new Regex(@"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

  if ((regex1.IsMatch(userAgent) || regex2.IsMatch(userAgent.Substring(0, 4))))
  {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

And you can get the User Agent with;

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent
```

**MVC3**

You could write a custom `ViewEngine` to perform this check and automatically show the .Mobile.cshtml view. Scott Hanselman did a good post on [how to write a mobile-aware ViewEngine](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek10NewMobileViewEnginesForASPNETMVC3SpeccompatibleWithASPNETMVC4.aspx) - adapting this should get you what you need;

```
public class MobileRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
  public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
    string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
    {
      string userAgent = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.UserAgent;
      string overrideViewName = DeviceIsMobile(userAgent) ? viewName + ".Mobile" : viewName;

      ViewEngineResult result = NewFindView(controllerContext, overrideViewName, masterName, useCache);

      // If we're looking for a Mobile view and couldn't find it try again without modifying the viewname
      if (overrideViewName.Contains(".Mobile") && (result == null || result.View == null))
      {
        result = NewFindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, useCache);
      }

      return result;
    }

    private ViewEngineResult NewFindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
    {
      // Get the name of the controller from the path
      string controller = controllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
      string area = "";

      try
      {
        area = controllerContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString();
      }
      catch
      {

      }

      // Create the key for caching purposes           
      string keyPath = Path.Combine(area, controller, viewName);

      // Try the cache           
      if (useCache)
      {
        //If using the cache, check to see if the location is cached.               
        string cacheLocation = ViewLocationCache.GetViewLocation(controllerContext.HttpContext, keyPath);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cacheLocation))
        {
          return new ViewEngineResult(CreateView(controllerContext, cacheLocation, masterName), this);
        }
      }

      // Remember the attempted paths, if not found display the attempted paths in the error message.           
      var attempts = new List<string>();

      string[] locationFormats = string.IsNullOrEmpty(area) ? ViewLocationFormats : AreaViewLocationFormats;

      // for each of the paths defined, format the string and see if that path exists. When found, cache it.           
      foreach (string rootPath in locationFormats)
      {
        string currentPath = string.IsNullOrEmpty(area) ? string.Format(rootPath, viewName, controller) : string.Format(rootPath, viewName, controller, area);

      if (FileExists(controllerContext, currentPath))
      {
        ViewLocationCache.InsertViewLocation(controllerContext.HttpContext, keyPath, currentPath);

        return new ViewEngineResult(CreateView(controllerContext, currentPath, masterName), this);
      }

      // If not found, add to the list of attempts.               
      attempts.Add(currentPath);
    }

    // if not found by now, simply return the attempted paths.           
    return new ViewEngineResult(attempts.Distinct().ToList());
  }
}
```

To use this, you need to add the ViewEngine to your `App_Start` and use;

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MobileRazorViewEngine());
```

**MVC4**

As pointed out by Andrus, the above answer using ViewEngines is targeted towards MVC3. In MVC4, you could extend `DefaultDisplayMode` to write your own custom check for mobile;

```
public class RegexMobileDisplay : DefaultDisplayMode
{
  public RegexMobileDisplay() : base("Mobile")
  {
    ContextCondition = context => DeviceIsMobile(context.Request.UserAgent);
  }
}
```

And registering this in App_Start;

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new RegexMobileDisplay());
```

I hope this helps.

Matt

Comment: Thank you. How to set `Browser.IsMobileDevice` value to true if this code dedects mobile device so that .Mobile.cshtml views will be used automatically?

Comment: I've reviewed my answer, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, great answer and link but it is written for MVC3. MVC4 uses *.Mobile.cshtml automatically. It looks like we need to override IsMobileDevice to return true for MC2180 . In this case proper views are picked automatically and re-writing view engine is not needed. 51degrees.mobi implements this for other mobile devices, IsMobileDevice has changed and mobile views are picked automatically. How to implement this for MC2180?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've reviewed my answer for MVC4 - I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you. Great. `Site.Mobile.cshtml` is now used properly. However `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` returns false. How to set IsMobileDevice value to true?

Comment: Use the custom method I wrote at the beginning of my post, using the regex.